# How do you pass external properties into an Android test case?

Tags: android, unit-testing, functional-testing

I'm writing an Android test case and I need to pass in a user name and id that is stored in a .properties file. I tried putting this in a "user.properties" file directly under the assets directory in my test project but that doesn't seem to work as getActivity().getAssets().open("user.properties") throws a FileNotFound exception. A buddy told me I could use the "-e key value" switch on the command line with a custom instrumentation runner but this seems like more work than necessary. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I should really drink my coffee before posting to StackOverflow! My stoopidity was calling: getActivity().getAssets().open("user.properties") instead of: getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets().open("user.properties")
Problem solved!